# Examining the DOM elements returned in a jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<p>Paragraph One</p>
<p>Paragraph Two</p>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
<script>
var x = $('p');
x.each(function(index) {
    $('body').append($(this).html().replace('<','&lt;') + '<br>');
});
</script>
```

I expected to see:

```
&lt;p>Paragraph One&lt;/p><br>
&lt;p>Paragraph Two&lt;/p><br>
```

But instead, the p tag itself is missing.

I'm trying to make my output look like console.log, which would identity x as two (2) paragraph elements.

It's getting the html within the paragraph, but console.log shows it AS a paragraph. So I guess I need to go up a level and then back down again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `$(this).html()` will only give you the content of the `<p>` element, not element itself.

Do this:

```
var x = $('p');
x.each(function(index) {
    var p_html = this.outerHTML || $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html();
    $('body').append(p_html.replace('<','&lt;') + '<br>');
});
```

This takes each `<p>` element, and gets its `.outerHTML` property (which is like `innerHTML` but includes the owner's tag as well).

If the `.outerHTML` property isn't supported *(I'm looking at you Firefox!)* then it uses the [`clone()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method to make a clone of the `<p>`, adds it to a new `<div>` and gets the `.html()` of the `<div>`.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn: You're welcome. Also note that you'll need to use a regular expression for the `.replace()` so that you can use the `g` global modifier in order to replace more than one `<` in a `<p>...</p>`. `p_html.replace(/</g,'&lt;')`

Comment: Oh, I was just about to post that as a comment, but thank you for validating what I had come up with.