# Examining a single DOM element returned in a jQuery object

Tags: jquery

This is a continuation of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499884/examining-the-dom-elements-returned-in-a-jquery-object).

I have: `var X = $('p');`

I'm trying to display on the page itself, what exactly is X[0].  If I use:

```
JSON.stringify(X)
```

It tells me that there's an object there, with a constructor, but not much else.
For a DOM element, like `X[0]` in this example, how do I display what exactly this object is?

I can loop through X.each and display the html, but there's so much more to a DOM element than the html.  There's all the attributes that are inherited.  There's probably a length property...  I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean by `what exactly this object is`? I'm not really sure what you're asking...

Comment: If I do: for(var prop in X) {log(prop);} then I get all kinds of properties, mostly inherited.  So I'd like to make sense of what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Now I see. I suggest to have a look at [*Firebug Light*](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). It embeds Firebug in any website. Maybe this helps you to figure out how to simulate `console.log`.

Or maybe just use it itself?

---

Use `console.log(X)` (reps. `console.log(X[0])`) . It is either available directly in Webkit (Chrome, Safari) or via Firebug for Firefox (don't know about IE or Opera, sorry).

`JSON.stringify` does not work, because you cannot serialize DOM elements (due to their recursive structure).

Comment: Ohhh.  That's why Chrome didn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

the eq function returns one jQuery element from a list

```
  $('p').eq(0);
```

the get function returns the HTML element

```
  $('p').get(0);
```

Comment: He wants a raw DOM object, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Oh wow!  Really?  I'll have to do a proof-of-concept on that.  That's new to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the properties of a native DOM element in the DOM subtab of the HTML tab in Firebug.

Comment: Thanks SLaks.  I guess what I'm doing is writing the DOM subtab on thepage itself so that the student can see it.  Here's my example: http://www.cfmzengarden.com/jQueryMatrix/Selectors/Intro/p.cfm

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a prototype-based language.  Rather than viewing the class the object was instantiated from you would inspect it's prototype.

```
X.prototype //reveals where it inherits all of its core methods/properties.
```

You can also loop through it's properties.

```
for(var prop in X) {
  //more props.
}
```

Comment: John,  thanks for this answer.  This helps me learn JavaScript a little more.  I'm putting together a matrix of JavaScript commands and this will help me with that.